# how to fetch first 20 contact from gmail using google api in android programmatically

Tags: android, google-api, android-contacts

I have 50 contacts in my gmail account. But it allow me to import only 25 contacts.So i have planned to send google api call again and again until all the contacts import into my mobile. How can i do that r any other solution is present rather than send api call again and again. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please show some code... how are you fetching 20 contacts...

Comment: now i can able to fetch more than 25 contacts at one shot. But sometime it may crash if more than 180 contacts

Comment: AndroidRaji, Can you please send me the source to fetch the gmail contacts in android? I need this.

Answer (score 1):

To import more than 25 contacts at one shot using following code:

https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?alt=json&max-results=5000

max-results denotes maximum number of contacts you want to import

Comment: The above link is not working, Can you please share me your full code.